# libapache2-redirtoservname package in precise?

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, package-management, apache2

I am not able to find the package libapache2-redirtoservname in precise or oneiric. 
Was it removed for some reason, and is there a way to get it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it has been removed. Check this link:
http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/net/libapache2-svn

Comment: that's not the same module